# Scala: How do I make those codes more simple?

Tags: scala

How do I make the following codes more simple? I am quite new to Scala. Thanks in advance!

Example 1:

```
def xsum(n: Int): Int = {

  if (n<10) n else n%10+xsum(n/10)
}
```

Example 2:

```
def num(n: Int): Int = {
  if (xsum(n)%10==0) n else (100-xsum(n))%10 + n*10
}

def xsum(n: Int): Int = {  
  if (n<10) n else n%10 + xsum(n/10)
}
```

Example 3:

```
def tru(n: Int): Boolean = {
  n==0 || xsum(n)%10==0
}
def xsum(n: Int): Int = {
  if (n<10) n else n%10 + xsum(n/10)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you mean by "simpler". The code is short enough as it is, and fairly easy to read. Maybe you want to have it more idiomatic, i.e. more functional, more "Scala-like"?

Answer (score 1):

```
def xsum(n:Int):Int= n.toString.map(_-'0').sum
```